# Oracle spfile value is empty

Tags: oracle

I create spfile from pfie but after restart spfile value is empty

```
SQL> show parameter pfile;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
spfile                               string


select value from v$parameter where name='spfile';

VALUE
NULL
```

Then create spfile from pfile

```
create spfile from pfile
```

startup

spfile empty again

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Do you have RAC or ASM ?

Comment: Oracle version 19c, ASM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    sqlplus / as sysdba 

    startup nomount pfile='/path/to/pfile/something.ora'
    
    create spfile from pfile='/path/to/pfile/something.ora'
```

Check if the spfile is created in ASM, it usually does it.

```
set asm home
set asm sid +ASM
asmcmd
ls
and now search for it using cd and ls
```

Set the path of your oracle home and oracle sid.

```
srvctl modify database -db SID_NAME -spfile +DG_DATA/spfile...ora => the path from the spfile which is in ASM.

sqlplus / as sysdba

startup force

show parameter spfi
```

Now your database, should be using spfile.

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: You are welcome